# заполнение img пустые места?

Tags: html, img

Как сделать так, чтобы картинки заполнили весь блок, без пустот?

```css
.photos-big-block {
  width: 500px;
}

.photos-list {
    display: table;
}

.photos-list img {
    width: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos-big-block box">
    <div class="photos-list">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-05/1622275855_23-phonoteka_org-p-krisha-zakat-art-krasivo-27.png" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-05/1622166068_17-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernii-anime-art-krasivo-19.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-06/1624118833_1-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernie-oboi-na-rabochii-stol-krasivo-1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/39788/pub_5b4cf7fa19656c00aa7082ac_5b4cf9dec7573000aaa8ba74/scale_1200" alt="">
        <img src="https://oir.mobi/uploads/posts/2021-03/1616371277_25-p-atmosfernie-anime-arti-27.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-04/1618641928_21-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernii-fon-na-rabochii-stol-21.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://assets.ppy.sh/user-profile-covers/3859265/3597c1fe6d72bb0a716c4c0b6bed0971c784eba11b0bf9f484df2c91d2801b70.jpeg" alt="">
        <img src="https://i11.fotocdn.net/s111/b15b43ac6b0bee11/public_pin_l/2504318452.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=a1fddb8579be2a9061a1dd78c61f9f8c-l&ref=rim&n=13&w=640&h=640" alt="">
        <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=c077386210fa2c409b64f3b942a7034d-l&ref=rim&n=13&w=640&h=640" alt="">
        <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=f34dd8c283a294bee6eef804ac63c675-l&ref=rim&n=13&w=1080&h=606" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-06/1622566841_4-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernie-arti-noch-krasivo-4.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rdQiY3b6CUo/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://img2.joyreactor.cc/pics/post/full/Aenami-artist-art-6563799.jpeg" alt="">
        <img src="https://catherineasquithgallery.com/uploads/posts/2021-02/1612844038_179-p-na-fone-alogo-zakata-220.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.photos-big-block {
  width: 500px;
}

.photos-list {
    display: table;
}

.photos-list img {
    width: 50%;
    height: 150px;        
    object-fit: containe;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos-big-block box">
    <div class="photos-list">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-05/1622275855_23-phonoteka_org-p-krisha-zakat-art-krasivo-27.png" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-05/1622166068_17-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernii-anime-art-krasivo-19.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-06/1624118833_1-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernie-oboi-na-rabochii-stol-krasivo-1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/39788/pub_5b4cf7fa19656c00aa7082ac_5b4cf9dec7573000aaa8ba74/scale_1200" alt="">
        <img src="https://oir.mobi/uploads/posts/2021-03/1616371277_25-p-atmosfernie-anime-arti-27.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-04/1618641928_21-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernii-fon-na-rabochii-stol-21.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://assets.ppy.sh/user-profile-covers/3859265/3597c1fe6d72bb0a716c4c0b6bed0971c784eba11b0bf9f484df2c91d2801b70.jpeg" alt="">
        <img src="https://i11.fotocdn.net/s111/b15b43ac6b0bee11/public_pin_l/2504318452.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=a1fddb8579be2a9061a1dd78c61f9f8c-l&ref=rim&n=13&w=640&h=640" alt="">
        <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=c077386210fa2c409b64f3b942a7034d-l&ref=rim&n=13&w=640&h=640" alt="">
        <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=f34dd8c283a294bee6eef804ac63c675-l&ref=rim&n=13&w=1080&h=606" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-06/1622566841_4-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernie-arti-noch-krasivo-4.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rdQiY3b6CUo/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://img2.joyreactor.cc/pics/post/full/Aenami-artist-art-6563799.jpeg" alt="">
        <img src="https://catherineasquithgallery.com/uploads/posts/2021-02/1612844038_179-p-na-fone-alogo-zakata-220.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!)

Comment: @ArSanta на здоровье!)

Answer (score 0):

Просто используйте flexbox.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

```css
.photos-big-block {
  width: auto;
}

.photos-list {
    width: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.photos-list img {
    width: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="photos-big-block box">
    <div class="photos-list">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-05/1622275855_23-phonoteka_org-p-krisha-zakat-art-krasivo-27.png" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-05/1622166068_17-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernii-anime-art-krasivo-19.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-06/1624118833_1-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernie-oboi-na-rabochii-stol-krasivo-1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-zen_doc/39788/pub_5b4cf7fa19656c00aa7082ac_5b4cf9dec7573000aaa8ba74/scale_1200" alt="">
        <img src="https://oir.mobi/uploads/posts/2021-03/1616371277_25-p-atmosfernie-anime-arti-27.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-04/1618641928_21-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernii-fon-na-rabochii-stol-21.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://assets.ppy.sh/user-profile-covers/3859265/3597c1fe6d72bb0a716c4c0b6bed0971c784eba11b0bf9f484df2c91d2801b70.jpeg" alt="">
        <img src="https://i11.fotocdn.net/s111/b15b43ac6b0bee11/public_pin_l/2504318452.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=a1fddb8579be2a9061a1dd78c61f9f8c-l&ref=rim&n=13&w=640&h=640" alt="">
        <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=c077386210fa2c409b64f3b942a7034d-l&ref=rim&n=13&w=640&h=640" alt="">
        <img src="https://im0-tub-ru.yandex.net/i?id=f34dd8c283a294bee6eef804ac63c675-l&ref=rim&n=13&w=1080&h=606" alt="">
        <img src="https://phonoteka.org/uploads/posts/2021-06/1622566841_4-phonoteka_org-p-atmosfernie-arti-noch-krasivo-4.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rdQiY3b6CUo/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="http://img2.joyreactor.cc/pics/post/full/Aenami-artist-art-6563799.jpeg" alt="">
        <img src="https://catherineasquithgallery.com/uploads/posts/2021-02/1612844038_179-p-na-fone-alogo-zakata-220.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```